# Impact an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Goal: Add points to multiple variables bundled in an object/group.**

I've tried it a few ways without success so far. 


First as an object:

```
    var allJobs = {
        job1: 0,
        job2: 0,
        job3: 0,
        }
```

I also tried an array of items:

```
    var allJobs = [
        job1 = 0,
        job3 = 0,
        job4 = 0,
    ]
```

The goal is to then add points to the items within the group:

```
$( "#addPoints" ).click(function() {
allJobs += 300; 
});
```

I need to be able to access them as individual jobs. So `console.log(job1)` should be 300.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS won't automatically map an operation over all the array/object elements. You have to loop explicitly.

```
var allJobs = [0, 0, 0];

$("#addPoints").click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < allJobs.length; i++) {
    allJobs[i] += 300;
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense! How could I modify to be able to console(job1) for example and get 300?

Comment: `console.log(allJobs[0]);`

Comment: Array elements don't have names, just indexes.

Comment: It works exactly the same no matter how many elements, that's the beauty of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could do it with object structure using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) with [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map):

```js
let allJobs = {
  job1: 0,
  job2: 0,
  job3: 0
}

const $addPoints = $("#add-points")

$($addPoints).click(function() {
  Object.keys(allJobs).map((job) => allJobs[job] += 300)
  console.log(allJobs)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add-points">add points</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it might help someone...this is the full solution I was trying to accomplish. The trick was to have an array of objects. Thanks to @Barmar for the help!

```
var jobs = [{

name: "Job1",
score: 0,
easy: false
}, {
name: "Job2",
score: 0,
easy: true
}, {
name: "Job3",
score: 0,
easy: true
}]

// How to loop through and add points

  $("#addPoints").click(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
  if  (jobs[i].easy == true){
  jobs[i].score += 100;
   }
  }
  console.log(jobs)
  });
```